# What could prevent iOS10 to show img hosted on Windows Server 2008

Tags: angularjs, cordova, windows-server-2008-r2, ios10, onsen-ui

I’d wrote an app who download pictures taken by trail cameras. It were working fine until user began to upgrade to iOS 10. Now, picture are not displayed anymore.

I can see in debugger the downloaded images and  with right urls.

Usually, images are saved as blob with localforage but i'd remove that part for debugging purpose.

ATS is also disabled.

Is someone experiencing same pattern ?  I worked a lot on this bug and i can't find solution.

There is some codes who do the same bug on ios10 :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsen-css-components.css"/>
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
    <script>
      var module = ons.bootstrap('my-app', ['onsen']);
      module.controller('AppController', function($scope) { 

          $scope.arPhotos = [{"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0222_925201681219PMOZT0C.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T23:58:16.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15772374,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347440,"version":0},"$loki":1,"src":"blob:file:///b1a2665a-22ae-4f0d-bf3d-3c8e67aeaa15","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"19:58:16","newDay":true,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0221_925201681219PM4LKnE.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T23:00:33.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15772372,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347441,"version":0},"$loki":2,"src":"blob:file:///178a2004-f9a9-4291-9ddf-7870b671406a","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"19:00:33","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0220_925201681218PMGr1XA.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T22:46:21.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15772370,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347441,"version":0},"$loki":3,"src":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0220_925201681218PMGr1XA.JPG","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"18:46:21","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":null}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0219_925201681218PMbP2Db.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T22:31:51.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15772369,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347441,"version":0},"$loki":4,"src":"blob:file:///6ce6a549-a06e-410b-92f3-095a412a4ee7","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"18:31:51","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0218_925201681218PMEs2os.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T19:42:05.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15772367,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347442,"version":0},"$loki":5,"src":"blob:file:///0f633eb2-5a53-45d4-b917-54ccc4350780","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"15:42:05","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0217_925201681217PMdmkUG.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T19:20:08.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15772365,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347442,"version":0},"$loki":6,"src":"blob:file:///da439895-549e-4530-9ba6-40f002437a14","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"15:20:08","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0216_925201681217PMP5oqQ.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T16:34:07.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15772363,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347442,"version":0},"$loki":7,"src":"blob:file:///4214c3b2-bdc5-4df0-a11e-d7d7806960ba","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"12:34:07","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0215_925201681216PMPoljT.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T16:20:21.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15772361,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347443,"version":0},"$loki":8,"src":"blob:file:///4e427a88-1ef1-468f-8136-13275b49221e","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"12:20:21","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0214_925201681216PMwGl3g.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T16:02:18.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15772360,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347443,"version":0},"$loki":9,"src":"blob:file:///66fc7636-fa3b-47c6-a5d3-3f1276720607","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"12:02:18","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0213_925201681216PMgA3Yd.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T13:39:35.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15772358,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347443,"version":0},"$loki":10,"src":"blob:file:///620af0a7-c37b-4a22-9610-77efc073087c","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"09:39:35","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0212_925201681215PMSNaUw.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T13:34:09.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15772356,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347444,"version":0},"$loki":11,"src":"blob:file:///fc62644c-b719-43a0-865e-0c1cb3e4f563","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"09:34:09","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0211_925201681419AMdmgHn.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T12:09:04.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757817,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347446,"version":0},"$loki":12,"src":"blob:file:///4723117a-2e70-476d-8ec5-6f017faf90ab","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"08:09:04","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0210_925201681419AMGQTSw.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T11:58:05.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757815,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347446,"version":0},"$loki":13,"src":"blob:file:///46dad07f-8df6-4a55-83b4-5ce34f1d757d","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"07:58:05","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0209_925201681419AMQneni.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T11:40:36.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757813,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347446,"version":0},"$loki":14,"src":"blob:file:///f24d8daf-b432-433d-858c-ccbed64a8845","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"07:40:36","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0208_925201681418AMq9gKO.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T08:25:19.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757811,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347448,"version":0},"$loki":15,"src":"blob:file:///13981971-0b3a-4a9e-a25f-be96a6685ceb","photo_date":"25/09/2016","photo_time":"04:25:19","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0207_925201681418AMXin7q.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T03:03:49.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757809,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347449,"version":0},"$loki":16,"src":"blob:file:///61084acc-53e5-4101-9661-71fdf3713f2e","photo_date":"24/09/2016","photo_time":"23:03:49","newDay":true,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0206_925201681417AMljJ5a.JPG","date":"2016-09-25T02:01:33.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757807,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347449,"version":0},"$loki":17,"src":"blob:file:///91aac3c1-505f-4c6e-bb12-73677f4e34e0","photo_date":"24/09/2016","photo_time":"22:01:33","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0205_925201681417AMuOd4P.JPG","date":"2016-09-24T23:30:09.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757804,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347449,"version":0},"$loki":18,"src":"blob:file:///ae973216-ce93-430e-aa09-678124fc0d44","photo_date":"24/09/2016","photo_time":"19:30:09","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0204_925201681417AMIP1wJ.JPG","date":"2016-09-24T23:20:00.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757802,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347450,"version":0},"$loki":19,"src":"blob:file:///3546cb8c-85aa-40cd-8a6e-6213741bdfe3","photo_date":"24/09/2016","photo_time":"19:20:00","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0203_925201681416AMcbql3.JPG","date":"2016-09-24T23:03:17.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757800,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347451,"version":0},"$loki":20,"src":"blob:file:///378aea5c-cd49-4f11-a4b9-2e0042b61639","photo_date":"24/09/2016","photo_time":"19:03:17","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0202_925201681416AMbK6wM.JPG","date":"2016-09-24T22:48:20.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757798,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347451,"version":0},"$loki":21,"src":"blob:file:///14f9ab39-c836-47d1-8e2b-a619c9fb5dde","photo_date":"24/09/2016","photo_time":"18:48:20","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0201_925201681415AM0ChYp.JPG","date":"2016-09-24T22:14:33.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757796,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347452,"version":0},"$loki":22,"src":"blob:file:///4976e6d3-ecb8-4e9b-bfb4-9bcc47332ea3","photo_date":"24/09/2016","photo_time":"18:14:33","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0200_925201681415AMk5uYi.JPG","date":"2016-09-24T21:54:47.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757794,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347453,"version":0},"$loki":23,"src":"blob:file:///dbd44d02-5c8f-41fe-8c16-3bee1446092b","photo_date":"24/09/2016","photo_time":"17:54:47","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0199_925201681414AMUV7TX.JPG","date":"2016-09-24T21:48:55.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757792,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347453,"version":0},"$loki":24,"src":"blob:file:///e12e4193-9535-4e23-847c-09e5fba783be","photo_date":"24/09/2016","photo_time":"17:48:55","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0198_925201681414AMfe1a8.JPG","date":"2016-09-24T21:29:08.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757790,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347453,"version":0},"$loki":25,"src":"blob:file:///055a3abc-bf0e-4ad9-9744-dd861414ceb8","photo_date":"24/09/2016","photo_time":"17:29:08","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0197_925201681414AMGZuW4.JPG","date":"2016-09-24T18:00:51.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757788,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347454,"version":0},"$loki":26,"src":"blob:file:///38b3bda4-7326-43ba-a0ba-7a2c22794e20","photo_date":"24/09/2016","photo_time":"14:00:51","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0196_925201681413AMko7Vs.JPG","date":"2016-09-24T17:42:17.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757786,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347454,"version":0},"$loki":27,"src":"blob:file:///69ece980-b7f5-4f30-8729-020a891f3961","photo_date":"24/09/2016","photo_time":"13:42:17","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}
            {"photo_url":"http://myspypoint.com/account/8944503526144479117/092016/PICT0195_925201681413AMyvj11.JPG","date":"2016-09-24T17:18:42.000Z","cam_id":12165,"photo_id":15757784,"meta":{"revision":0,"created":1474985347454,"version":0},"$loki":28,"src":"blob:file:///2995128d-db68-44dd-bbf1-4a893ba3e0f3","photo_date":"24/09/2016","photo_time":"13:18:42","newDay":false,"w":520,"h":390,"blob":{}}];
        ons.ready(function() {
          // Init code here
        });   
      });
      module.controller('PageController', function($scope) {

      });
    </script>
    <style>
    .photo_img {
        width:28%;
        padding:10px;
        float:left;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="AppController">
    <ons-tabbar>
  <ons-tab page="home.html" active="true">
        <ons-icon icon="ion-home"></ons-icon>
        <span style="font-size: 14px">Home</span>
      </ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>

<ons-template id="home.html">
        <div class="photo_frame" ng-repeat="photo in arPhotos track by $index">  
            <img id="img-{{photo.photo_id}}" class="photo_img" ng-src="{{photo.photo_url}}" photoloader="loader-{{photo.photo_id}}" style="width:30%"/>
        </div>

</ons-template>

  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT2:**
There is what I see if i try to look at picture in safari inspector with ressources tab : [image: safari can't show image]

Error translation : An error append when trying to load ressource.

**EDIT 3** : new image
[image: images are downloaded but not shown]

**EDIT 4**

I've also create an issue on apache bugs tracker (there)[https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11912].  It seem it's related to server.

So I've tried to enable TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.0 but no success here

Comment: I know this isn't very helpful, but you could also ask at https://community.onsen.io . I currently cannot help you but maybe some other people there may be able to.

Comment: may be i'd find out.. I still have to verify. It could be a problem with [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview) and iOS10  

`Important

An iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0 must include in its Info.plist file the usage description keys for the types of data it needs to access or it will crash. To access a user’s photo data specifically, it must include NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription and NSCameraUsageDescription.`

Comment: I'm not using photolibrary nor camera so it should not be that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug didn't come from cordova nor windows server 2008 but from image exif.  Apple did something in his update who block image with deffective exif.